# C++ Инициализатор собственных коллекций

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, конструктор

Есть класс `Array<T>`.

Пример использования:

```
Array<string> a;
a.add("test");
a.add("...");
//...
```

Как мне реализовать вариант инициализации

```
Array<string> a = {"str1", "str2"};
```

?

Comment: добавить соотвествующий конструктор принимающий список инициализации (возможно начиная с с++11)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Взято здесь http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/C11/C11_initializer_list.php

В целом, Вам нужно написать что то  такое

```
Array(const std::initializer_list<T> &v) {
    for (auto itm : v) {
        add(itm);
    }
}
```

(так как у Вас там шаблоны, нужно это учесть. Но Вашего кода нет, поэтому и нет гарантии на компиляцию).

Comment: `auto itm` или `auto &itm` или `auto &&itm`? И вообще, а на compile-time переложить нельзя?

Comment: @Qwertiy что переложить?  преждевременную оптимизацию? Смотря что там внутри. Если внутри класса обычный вектор, то можно в одну строку, а если там супер навороченное ассемблерное?

Comment: Ну initializer_list по моим представлениям нужен, чтобы понаписать всего в фигурные скобки и оно уже при компиляции разместилось как надо в памяти без лишних вызовов. А эта штука из ответа по сути просто берёт какой-то промежуточный массив и в рантайме перекладывает. Или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: Думаю, Вы почитали о std::move и сишном способе инициализации структур. компилятор у может быть сложно угадать всю внутреннюю структуру Вашего класса

Comment: @Abyx А кстати, почему?

Comment: Огромное спасибо))

Answer (score 0):

Можете поступить так-же как разработчики stl в `std::array`

```
template<class T, int size>
class Array{
public:
    T data[size];
    //...
};

Array<std::string, 10> arr = {"1", "2", "3"};
```